# SFML+OpenGL: How to work with them at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, c++14, sfml

I try to use SFML+OpenGL together, but I don't understand it good. In tutorials there was written that I shoud use **window.setActive(false)**.

My code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML works!");

    sf::FloatRect frect;
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("PaPYRUS.ttf");
    int z=45;
    int x=0, y=0;
    stringstream l;
    l<<z;
    cout<<l.str()<<endl;
    string s="Lololololooooooooooooooooooooooooo0000000000oooooooooo\nlololololol  "+l.str()+"  lololo";
    sf::Text text(s, font, 20);
    text.setPosition(20, 40);
    frect=text.getGlobalBounds();
    cout<<frect.height<<" "<<frect.left<<" "<<frect.top<<" "<<frect.width;

    bool running=true;
    int x2=0, y2=0;
    sf::CircleShape shape(30);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);


    while (running)
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            x2+=2;
            y2++;
            shape.setPosition(x2, y2);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                running=false;
        }

        // From that place problems begin
        window.setActive(true);
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        window.setActive(false);
        window.draw(shape);
        window.draw(text);

        window.setActive(true);
            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            for (float i = 0; i<2 * 3.14; i += float(3.14 / 4))
            {
                glVertex2f(20 + 5*sinf(i), 40  + 6*cosf(i));
            }
        window.setActive(false);

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment OpenGL part with drawing of circle, all is ok. I put window.setActive(false) in other places of code, but it don't work.

Errors: 
"Failed to activate the window's context"
"Failed to deactivate OpenGL context: A"

Please, if you can, show how to make this code right.

Comment: Using of window.setActive(false) is error. Later tried with window.pushGLStates(); and window.popGLStates();, but nothing good

Answer (score 1):

`pushGLStates` and `popGLStates` are what you should be using. As per the [tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-opengl.php#using-opengl-together-with-the-graphics-module) you need to push the states before drawing with the SFML graphics module, then pop the states when you are done and want to return to using raw opengl:

```
glDraw...

window.pushGLStates();

window.draw(...);

window.popGLStates();

glDraw...
```

If you still have trouble, there's an [example](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/examples/opengl/OpenGL.cpp) included with the source, which you can use to verify there isn't a more serious problem

Comment: where should use the window.clear() and other drawing operation using sfml.